# How do I interact with my primaryStage in JavaFX class from another method?

Tags: java, windows, javafx, javafx-8

I am currently testing out some JavaFX code to get more into this language and I wanted to have a Window with a button called "Iconify" which does minimize the window when clicked.
[Here you can see how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGSlF.png)

I am working with FXML (Scene Builder) and so I usually do not initialize or declare Nods (Components) in my class. When I do all the stuff in the `start(Stage primaryStage)` method, minimizing does work, when I use this code: `buttonIconify.setOnAction(event -> stage.setIconified(true));` So, actually, when I try to use `.setIconified(true)` in my `start` Method is works fine. But when I try to use it from another method like `public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)` it doesn't for some reason.

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8863)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at app.Main.handleButtonAction(Main.java:39)
    ... 58 more
```

Gigantic...

I have no idea, why it doesn't work outside the

`@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception`

method.

**My full class code:**

```
package app;

import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage stage;

    @FXML
    private Button buttonIconify;
    @FXML
    private Button buttonExit;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX Test Range");

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        // scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Stylesheet.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == buttonIconify) {
            stage.setIconified(true);
        }

        if (event.getSource() == buttonExit) {
            Platform.exit();
        }
    }
}
```

**FXML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="app.Main">
    <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" spacing="30.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <Button fx:id="buttonIconify" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="170.0" text="Iconify" />
        <Button fx:id="buttonExit" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="170.0" text="Exit" />
    </HBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @MMAdams Doesn't really explain why `stage` is null in this case.

Comment: @James_D, I realized that after I had flagged, whoops! I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 2):

Your handler method `handleButtonAction` is called on the controller. You only initialize the field `stage` in the instance of the `Application` class that is created when you call `launch()`: it is never initialized in the controller. Consequently when you try to call `stage.setIconified()` in the controller, you get a null pointer exception.

It is always a mistake to use the `Application` class as the class for the controller, as it leads to confusion about which fields are initialized in which instances.

Create a separate class for the controller, and access the window in it in the usual way:

```
@FXML
public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == buttonIconify) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) buttonIconify.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setIconified(true);
    }

    if (event.getSource() == buttonExit) {
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, I recommend using different handlers for different actions, instead of one big handler with (potentially) a whole bunch of `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `NetBeans`. It will set the project up for you. In your example, you are combining two different ways to set up a `JavaFX` projects. Look [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/72/java/javafx-setup.html).

[image]

In the image above you have `JavaFX Application` and `JavaFX FXML Application`. The project structure for these two types of applications is different. If you want to create a project that uses `FXML` and `Controllers` use `JavaFX FXML Application`. At this point in your coding, you should not have to write anything in the `Main`. Later, once you get to more advance MCV concepts you might.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Platform.runLater()` around your code, for example:

```java
public static void winMin() {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stage.setIconified(true);
        }
    });
}
```